Unable to create Zipkin data source for Grafana
I'd need to set up a demo which shows in a Grafana Dashboard the traces collected in a Zipkin Server.
I've setup the following docker-compose.yml file:
services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE=Admin
    networks:
      - monitoring

  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin:latest
    container_name: zipkin
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"
      - "9410:9410"
    networks:
      - monitoring

networks:
  monitoring:
    driver: bridge

Unfortunately, when I add and test the zipkin data source in Grafana I get the error "Bad gateway" and I see the following error in the Grafana logs:
8.929235577Z level=error msg="Proxy request failed" err="dial tcp [::1]:9411: connect: connection refused"
grafana     | logger=context userId=0 orgId=1 uname= t=2024-07-26T18:11:58.929274798Z level=error msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/api/datasources/proxy/uid/edsxwlxtvek1sa/api/v2/services status=502 remote_addr=172.19.0.1 time_ms=2 duration=2.458376ms size=0 referer=http://localhost:3000/connections/datasources/edit/edsxwlxtvek1sa handler=/api/datasources/proxy/uid/:uid/* status_source=downstream
grafana     | logger=authn.service t=2024-07-26T18:11:59.0086489Z level=warn msg="Failed to authenticate request" client=auth.client.session error="user token not found"

It seems that token authentication is in place but I have not set up any option besides the Zipkin URL (http://localhost:9411).
Is there a way to overcome this issue? Maybe some default options are blocking access to the Zipkin server?
Thanks
